# Splitting a text using javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am having string called 'santhosh'. I wish to split this text as 's,a,n,t,h,o,s,h' using javascript. Is it possible? And want to save it in an array.

And I wish to check whether the splitted character is string or Numeric is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an empty string as the separator argument of the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Split) method:

```
var array = "santhosh".split('');
// ["s", "a", "n", "t", "h", "o", "s", "h"]
```

Comment: i wish to store it in an array

Comment: Now I wish to check whether the splitted character is string or Numeric is it possible?

Comment: If you want to check whether a single character is numeric, you could use something like:
`/^\d$/.test(x)` where x is a variable that contains the character you want to test.

Comment: @susanthosh: If you want to ask a new question it's better to create a new question instead of adding comments to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myString = "Hello";

var mySplitResult = myString.split('');

document.write("The first element is " + mySplitResult[0]); 
document.write("<br /> The second element is  " + mySplitResult[1]); 
document.write("<br /> The third forth is  " + mySplitResult[2]);
document.write("<br /> The fourth element is  " + mySplitResult[3]);
document.write("<br /> The fifth element is  " + mySplitResult[4]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet returns an array object:

```
"santhosh".split('') // s,a,n,t,h,o,s,h
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function:

string.split(separator, limit)

-just give the seperators as "" , it will split all charactors in the string.